# Even numbers and Euler's Totient Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $m$ is even, $m|r$ and $\phi (r) \leq \phi (m)$, prove that $r=m$.

I only knew the converse is also true $\phi (r) \geq \phi (m)$ but i dont know how the condition $m$ is even is gonna help, please helps.

Comment: The condition on $m$ is necessary since, e.g., $3\mid6$, $\phi(6)\le\phi(3)$, but $6\ne3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exploit the multiplicativity of the totient function. Here we have:
$$ m=2^{\alpha}p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_j^{\alpha_j},\quad r=2^{\alpha+\varepsilon}p_1^{\alpha_1+\varepsilon_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_j^{\alpha_j+\varepsilon_j} q_{j+1}^{\varepsilon_{j+1}}\cdot\ldots\cdot q_k^{\varepsilon_{k}}$$
where $p_i,q_i$ are odd primes and $\alpha,\alpha_i,\varepsilon,\varepsilon_i\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\alpha>0$. If we set
$$Q=\prod_{r=j+1}^{k} q_{r}^{\varepsilon_r}$$
we have:
$$\frac{\varphi(r)}{\varphi(m)}=2^{\varepsilon}\varphi(Q)\prod_{s=1}^{j}p_s^{\varepsilon_s}.$$
If this ratio is $\leq 1$ that necessarily $\varepsilon=0,\phi(Q)=1,\varepsilon_s=0$, hence $r=m$.